# Total bond dissociation temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, temperature, plasma-chemistry

I understand that covalent bonds break at a dissociation energy $D_0$ that is a function of the particular bond.  And it looks like [an upper bound on $D_0$ is known for possible covalent bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy#Strongest_bonds_and_weakest_bonds).

It's unclear to me whether continuing to add energy to a mass will at some point guarantee that all covalent bonds are broken, or whether there are other physical processes that could continue to absorb energy so as to prevent total homolysis.

Is there some temperature above which the bonds cannot be maintained in any substantial way?  I.e., for any soup of atoms is there a temperature sufficiently high that no molecular compounds can exist?

How hot does thermal plasma need to be to eliminate virtually all chemical bonding?

Comment: Maybe this idea is not meant to generalize over entirety of bonds. Because bonds form in so radically different environments.

Comment: @Proscionexium if necessary, yes.  I'm assuming that covalent bonds are both the strongest and the most meaningful for chemical properties, but if there are other inter-atomic bonds that can survive energy sufficient to totally homolyze a mass, and that affect the chemo-physical behavior of a mass of atoms, that would be a helpful answer (though perhaps to a related question I should pose?).

Comment: How is this any different from your old question? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34964/plasma-creation-and-condensation besides being more focused...

Comment: @Mithoron that one is about what happens *if* all bonds are broken and then the mass is cooled.  This one is *whether* heating actually *will* break all bonds (and if so, at what point).

Comment: *sigh* Heat stuff to million K and what we call chemistry is gone. There is no sharp threshold. What would you want, point when less than one ppb of CO remains undissociated?

Comment: @Mithoron Just an elaboration of that would be a helpful answer.  E.g., "There is no finite temperature at which all covalent bonds are broken, because ....?"  And maybe, "The dissociated fraction of a mass varies with *what functional form of temperature?*, or *what other variables?*"

Comment: There certainly are such temperatures, million K should be plenty enough. But yeah, an answer like that would be nice.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99110/at-what-temperature-can-molecules-no-longer-form though...

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61621/dissociation-of-diatomic-molecules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [At what temperature can molecules no longer form?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99110/at-what-temperature-can-molecules-no-longer-form)